# Google Analytics showing message: Bad Event Tracking Code

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, event-tracking

Google Analytics is showing message "Bad Event Tracking Code" for several my projects. Even for mobile app profile too.

"**The message: "The Landing Pages report has a (not set) entry. Verify that tracking code for property (my app name) sends a _trackPageview hit and that it does this before sending any events."**

Has somebody got similar issue?
and how to solve this issue because I read about this and can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think an issue with you tracking code that have to generate with you google analytics account Here it is step by step description about how to Setting Up Google analytics for Your App

**step:1**

Go to `www.google.com/analytics`. The homepage should appear like so:

[image]

**step:2:**

- If you do not have a Google account, you will need to create one now by selecting Create an Account on the top-right side of the page.
  or sign in in this page.
- Once you have logged in, you simply need to click the Access Google Analytics button on the top right.

[image]

**Step:3**

- The first screen you see lists all of your accounts.
- If you have clients, typically you will have one account set up for each.
- If you are new to Google Analytics you will only have the first account you set up.

[image]

**step:4**

- Select the Admin view on the top right.
- To see the main dashboard area for managing your Accounts, Properties, and Views.

[image]

**step:5**

- Select the Property drop-down and click on the Create new property item, like so:

[image]

**step:6**

- Google then asks you to submit the details for the app you want to track.
- Make sure to choose Mobile app at the top and enter the information as required.
- In the Setting up your property section, enter "Cloud App" for the App Name.

[image]

**step:7**

- After accepting the terms of service, the website takes you to a page with your tracking ID and the download link for the SDK.

[image]

Before you do anything else, write down your app’s Tracking ID, which will be of the form ID UA-XXXXXXXX-Y. 
 Keep the ID handy, because you will need it soon. [For full of description please visit raywenderlich blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios)

Comment: Wonderfull answer. What an explanation with image !! Great !

Comment: I have followed the same but the error after one months of the implementing the GA in my application

Answer (score 0):

I have received similar errors. However, after testing and checking all the tags, all seem to be in order. I read on PBS that these are false positive alerts, where the errors in fact in correct.

http://spiblog.pbs.org/2014/08/the-art-of-analytics-google-analytics.html